# Server-side actionscript: 'Method not found' error on NetConnection

Tags: actionscript, flash-media-server, netconnection

The 'client' property of NetConnection instances seems to behave differently on the server side.

Say I have FMS apps A and B. Now I want to connect from B to A using NetConnection like this:

```
var bClient = new NetConnection();
bClient.client = { foo:function(){ trace ('Foo called!') } }
bClient.connect(APP_A_URI);
```

App A accepts the client and then issues `client.call('foo')`.

In the logs from B I then get `Sending error message: Method not found (foo)`.

Obviously there's no 'client' object on then server version of NetConnection.
If I define `bClient.foo = function(){ ... }` instead, it all works but I have to redefine all methods on the NetConnection instance which seems dumb.

How do U guys treat this situtation? Inherit NetConnection or its prototype or what? : )
A little example would be much appreciated!

Thanks, Carsten!